# How to do a LIMIT with GROUP BY in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I have 400 players with 4 different skills I want to group them by skill but take only 20 from each skill

```
players.groupBy {
    it.skill
}
```

So the total is 80 i.e 20 from each

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [mapValues](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map-values.html) with [take](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html)

```
players.groupBy {
    it.skill
}.mapValues{
    it.value.take(20)
}
```